# Having issues adjusting layout to fit the whole screen

Tags: css

I'm a beginner and would like to get some help and see where I'm making a mistake. I've adjusted my css to try to make the footer drop to the bottom of the page no matter the screen size that's view the page. I tried adjusting the body height to be at 100%, but that did not work. 
I'm trying to make it so the bottom footer is just below the fold, so it can only be seen once you scroll down, and not seen we you first get to the page.

If there is any advice on how I can solve my issue, it would be much appreciated thanks.

Here are some pictures to give you an example & the CSS

Mobile
[image: Mobile]

Tablet Vertical
[image: Tablet Vertical]

Tablet Horizontal
[image: Tablet Horizontal]

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #000000;
        width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

h1, h2, h3 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #000000;

}

h1 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-top: 1.8em;
    text-align:left;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 1.6em;
}

p, ul, ol {
    margin-top: 0;
    line-height: 100%;
}

ul, ol {
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
}

a:hover { 
text-decoration: underline;
    color: #000000;
}

#wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;

}

#bottom-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    position:relative;
    bottom:0;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
    background: url(images/blue-background.jpg) repeat-x left top;

}

#bottom {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 960px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}

.abouttext {
    width: 625px;

    margin: 10px auto;
}

.three {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 10px 140px;

}

.container {
    width: 880px;

    margin: 10px auto;
}

  #container {
    display: table;
    }

  #row  {
    display: table-row;
    }

  #left, #right, #middle {
    display: table-cell;
    }

/* Header */

#header-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 110px;
    background: url(images/blue-background.jpg) repeat-x left top;

}

#header {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    font-weight: bold;  
}


/* Banner */

#banner {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100px;
    background: url(images/img04.jpg) no-repeat center bottom;
}

#banner .image-style {
    border: 15px solid #F4F4F4;
}


/* Logo */

#logo {
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #000000;
}

#logo h1, #logo p {
}

#logo h1 {
    padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
    font-size: 3.0em;
}

#logo p {
    margin-top: -10px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
} 

#logo p a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#logo a {
    border: none;
    background: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

/* Splash */

#splash {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #E7E2DC;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    font-size: 18px;
}

div.home-rt, div.cat{
 /*width:310;height:355;*/
 text-align:center;/*border:solid 2px #e0e0e0;*/
 margin: 0 auto;
 vertical-align:top;
 display:inline-block;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.iPad_1, .iPad_2, .iPad_3, .iPad_4, .iPad_Air, .iPad_Mini, .iPad_MiniRetina
{
margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
.iPhone_2G, .iPhone_3G, .iPhone_3GS, .iPhone_4, .iPhone_4S, .iPhone_5, .iPhone_5C, .iPhone_5S
{
margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
#splash div.home-rt {
    /*margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;*/
    width:310;
    height:355;
    background:#fff;
}
#splash .home-rt {
 text-align:center !important;
}
#splash span {
    color: #313131;
}



/* Search */

#search {
    float: right;
    width: 280px;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#search form {
    height: 41px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0 0 20px;
}

#search fieldset {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}

#search-text {
    width: 170px;
    padding: 6px 5px 2px 5px;
    border: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    font: normal 11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #5D781D;
}

#search-submit {
    width: 50px;
    height: 22px;
    border: none;
    background: #B9B9B9;
    color: #000000;
}

/* Menu */

#menu {
    float: right;
    width: 500px;
    height: 90px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

#menu ul {
    float: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: normal;
}

#menu li {
    float: left;
}

#menu a {
    display: block;
    margin-right: 1px;
    padding: 10px 0px 15px 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border: none;
}

#menu a:hover, #menu .current_page_item a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
}

#menu .current_page_item a {
}

/* Page */

#page {
    padding: 30px 0px 0px 0px;
}

/* Content */

#content {
    float: left;
    width: 620px;
    padding: 0px 40px 0px 0px;
    background: url(images/img05.jpg) no-repeat right 40px;
}

.post {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.post .title {
    padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
    letter-spacing: -3px;
}

.post .title a {
    border: none;
    color: #7D7764;
}

.post .meta {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.post .meta .date {
    float: left;
}

.post .meta .posted {
    float: right;
}

.post .meta a {
}

.post .entry {
    padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: justify;
}

.links {
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.more {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 88px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 2px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: url(images/img08.jpg) no-repeat left top;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.comments {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 88px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 2px 0px 0px 0px;
    background: url(images/img08.jpg) no-repeat left top;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

/* Sidebar */

#sidebar {
    float: right;
    width: 320px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    color: #000000;
}

#sidebar h2 {
    padding: 0px 0px 30px 0px;
    letter-spacing: -3px;
}

#sidebar a {
    border: none;
}

#sidebar a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/* Calendar */

#calendar {
}

#calendar_wrap {
    padding: 20px;
}

#calendar table {
    width: 100%;
}

#calendar tbody td {
    text-align: center;
}

#calendar #next {
    text-align: right;
}

/* Three Column Footer Content */

#footer-content {
    background: url(images/img04.png) no-repeat center top;
    color: #E2B8C6;
}

#footer-bg {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 170px 0px;
}

#footer-content h2 {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
    letter-spacing: -2px;
    text-shadow: 1px 2px 0px #861F40;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#column1 {
    float: left;
    width: 320px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#column2 {
    float: left;
    width: 320px;
}

#column3 {
    float: right;
    width: 320px;
}

/* Footer */

#footer {
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
    /*background: url(images/img04.png) no-repeat center top;*/
}

#footer p {
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 150px;
    line-height: normal;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000000;
}

#footer a {
    color: #000000;
}



#marketing {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 20px 0px 10px 0px;
    border-top: 1px solid #E3E3E3;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E3E3E3;
}

#marketing .text1 {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    letter-spacing: -2px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000000;
}

#marketing .text2 {
    float: right;
}

#marketing .text2 a {
    display: block;
    width: 252px;
    height: 38px;
    padding: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
    background: url(images/img07.jpg) no-repeat left top;
    letter-spacing: -2px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000000;
}

.box1 {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100px;
    background: url(images/img04.jpg) no-repeat center bottom;
}

.list-style1 {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}

.list-style1 li {
    padding: 7px 0px 7px 0px;
    border-top: 1px dashed #E7E2DC;
}

.list-style1 .first {
    padding-top: 0px;
    border-top: none;
}


.list-style2 {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}

.list-style2 li {
    padding: 7px 0px 7px 0px;
    background: url(images/img06.png) repeat-x left top;
}

.list-style2 a {
    color: #E2B8C6;
}

.list-style2 a:hover {
    color: #C76485;
}

.list-style2 .first {
    padding-top: 0px;
    background: none;
}
```

Comment: i think you want `#bottom-wrapper{position:absolute;}` and `body{position:relative;}` for expected result.

Comment: I tried changing it, but now the bottom footer completely disappeared, what are you thoughts? The changing or not chaining the body, doesnt have any effect on the final layout

Comment: to be honest, that is the quick and dirty way that breaks on some browsers (first hand experience). Check out http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/ .also you may get more responses if you provide a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Sticky footer is usually a good bet, at least for desktop. If you're using the position absolute trick then make sure you also include a negative margin on your #wrapper element equivalent to the height of the footer. Otherwise you'll end up with the footer always being out of view and you'll need to scroll to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned:

> I'm trying to make it so the bottom footer is just below the fold, so it can only be seen once you scroll down, and not seen we you first get to the page.

I don't think css alone is capable of doing this, I got a [quick jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yummisashimi/sPB9k/2/) for you that may help.

```
windowHeight = $(window).height();
footerHeight = $(".footer").height();

$(".wrap").css({
    "height": windowHeight + footerHeight
});
```

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm trying to do, I appreciate the help. So i don't need to do anything to the css, just the javascript?

Comment: @user3352949 you will still need to setup sticky footer with CSS. Note the `html, body { height: 100% }` and `.innerWrap { min-height: 100%}`